# How can I manipulate objects in a subView?

Tags: ios, uiview

Got away from XCode programming for a while, now I'm starting back and feel like I'm starting ALL over.  I have a simple example that's driving me crazy.
I have created a sub class of UIView called Word1View and added it to my storyboard.
I declared it as a property in the main view controller and attached it as an IBOutlet to the main view.  I can draw on this view using Core Graphics with no problems (rectangles, lines, etc). Here's the code in the ".h" file.  The property is synthesized correctly in the ".m"

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Word1View.h"

@interface Board3ViewController : UIViewController
{
    Word1View *word1View;
}   
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet Word1View *word1View;
@end
```

Now, here's the problem.  I have added a UILabel (I will be adding UIImageFiles later)
in Word1View.h it appears as so:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Word1View : UIView
{
    UILabel *testLabel;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *testLabel;
@end
```

This property is also synthesized correctly. The UILabel was added to the view in the main storyboard. I tried to make this an IBOutlet, but could not hook it up as long as it was part of the subview.  I tried to access the UILabel in my main view controller as so:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.view addSubview:word1View];
NSLog(@"Label text is: %@", word1View.testLabel.text);
```

I don't have any access to that label as evidenced by the output to NSLog which is:
Board3[14520:c07] Label text is: (null)

I would like to be able to access the label (change its text, properties etc) from my main View Controller.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: To eliminate one category of mistakes, you should omit the explicit instance variable declarations. Just declare your properties and the compiler will now automatically create the instance variables for you. By defining your own, you open up the potential of confusion between your explicitly declared instance variables and the ones that the compiler now synthesizes for you.

Comment: You haven't shown us (a) how you created `word1View`; nor (b) how `word1View` creates the `testLabel`, so it's hard to advise you.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. word1View was created in IB and added to the main view of my main view controller. Thanks to another response I created testLabel using    word1View.testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 10)];  Now the text I put into the label is properly assigned.  The problem is the label does not appear on the view. How can I make the label appear in the view?

Comment: You need to call `addSubview` to add your label to your view. But why not add the label in IB, too?

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your `UILabel` and give it some text.

```
wordView1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
wordView.text = @"Some Text";
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeff.  Just FYI, word1View was created in IB and added to the main view of my main view controller. I took your advice and added:   word1View.testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 10)];  Now the text I put into the label is properly assigned.  The problem is the label does not appear on the view. How can I make the label appear in the view?

Comment: You need to `addSubview` for any control you want to add to your view.